# How to drop all columns that contain a certain character

Tags: sql, sqlite

I created a table and want to remove any column that contains the ':' character in its name

```
ALTER TABLE DraftTable
DROP COLUMN FROM DraftTable
WHERE COLUMN IN ':'
```

I feel like the final line is what I'm missing, or that my syntax could be off. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You can’t do that in the way you are trying to. You need to query the information schema for the columns  and dynamically construct the alter statements. If you want to also automatically run the statement then you’d need to write the whole process in a stored procedure

Comment: I see, thank you. Do you know of any documentation that could help me with that? Or if there's another method of dropping duplicate columns without having to type them out individually.

Comment: I’m sure the documentation for your DBMS would be a good place to start